# thread question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsthread, springboard

I am hooked into SpringBoard method, i want to wait a certain event to happen and then continue my code, but whatever i try - i think it pauses the main thread and all threads stop then. My code is:

```
+(void) startc {
    while([currentNumber isEqual:@""])
    {
        NSLog(@"waiting until currentNumber is not empty %@", currentNumber);
    }
}

id replaced_SBCallAlert_initWithCall_(id self, SEL _cmd, CTCallRef call) {  // Note the 
        NSLog(@"calling replaced");
            [cdBackground startc];
        original_SBCallAlert_initWithCall_(sbc, scc, cls); 
            return NULL;
    }
```

currentNumber is updated in another thread, but this code blocks it.

Comment: first of all it seems you have forgotten to add the -(id) instead of only the id.

Comment: actually this is mixed, c & obj c

Comment: Ah okay, never used that so ignore that comment:)

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop in `startc` is effectively a spin lock, and will prevent any further progress on a thread executing it until `currentNumber` is not `@""`. If that same thread is the one responsible for changing `currentNumber`, then yes - you have a deadlock. It looks like this is the case, as I guess you're expecting the call `original_SBCallAlert_initWithCall_` to change this variable but are getting stuck inside the previous line's `startc` call.

In this case, you'll have to change the way your program is designed. You could put `startc` in a background thread (look at `NSThread`) and use either another spin lock, `NSCondition` or key-value observing to "wake up" when `currentNumber` has changed. You can then use `NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread …` (assuming you have a runloop) to kick off your code again in the "main" thread, or carry on in your background thread.

Comment: actually currentNumber is changed with notification from an observer on a background thread. i just want to wait few seconds before calling  original_SBCallAlert_initWithCall_(sbc, scc, cls); but this blocks all threads.  btw  replaced_SBCallAlert_initWithCall is not called by me. i am hooked into SpringBoard and SprnigBoard calls it. Maybe that's the reason that the whole device freezes if I sleep in this function?